# Join on a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

I have the following pl sql proc, I'm trying to join a table on a CUR

```
FETCH CUR INTO V_CTR_ID,V_TRXN_INTRL_REF_ID,V_TRXN_DT,V_ACCT_INTRL_ID,V_TRXN_BASE_AM;
        EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
        --dbms_output.put_line('Enter CUR');
        OPEN CUR1 FOR  SELECT distinct CTR.OCCUPATION,CTR.TAX_ID
                         FROM
                            BR_CTR_TRANS BR join CUR on
                            CUR.V_TRXN_INTRL_REF_ID=BR.TRANS_REF_ID AND CUR.V_ACCT_INTRL_ID=BR.ACCT_IDENTIFIER AND CUR.V_TRXN_BASE_AM=BR.TRANS_AMT_BASE AND CUR.V_TRXN_DT=BR.TRANS_DT 
                            join CTR_XML_BR_COND CTR
                            on
                            BR.BR_CTR_SUM_REF_ID=CTR.CTR_ID;
```

The error I'm getting is, the CUR is considered as table, and it's giving table or view doesn't exist. Can someone help?

Comment: One would generally FETCH only after their cursor is open. Furthermore you open `CUR1` but FETCH (out of order) `CUR`. Perhaps this is proper syntax though in whatever RDBMS you are using...? By the way, what RDBMS is this? At any rate, I have a suspicion the join isn't the issue.

Comment: Saw the mention of `pl sql proc` and updated the tags accordingly. Apologies for missing that. So I believe what I stated is accurate. 1) Declare your cursor 2) Open your cursor 3)Fetch your cursor into the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot JOIN to a cursor, but you can use the use the fetched  values in a subsequent SQL statement. In this case remove the 'join cur' and move the on clause conditions to a 'where' clause.

```
fetch cur into v_ctr_id,v_trxn_intrl_ref_id,v_trxn_dt,v_acct_intrl_id,v_trxn_base_am;
        exit when cur%notfound;
        --dbms_output.put_line('Enter CUR');
        open cur1 for  select distinct ctr.occupation,ctr.tax_id
                         from br_ctr_trans br 
                         join ctr_xml_br_cond ctr onbr.br_ctr_sum_ref_id=ctr.ctr_id
                        where 1=1
                          and cur.v_trxn_intrl_ref_id=br.trans_ref_id 
                          and cur.v_acct_intrl_id=br.acct_identifier 
                          and cur.v_trxn_base_am=br.trans_amt_base 
                          and cur.v_trxn_dt=br.trans_dt;
```

Comment: You are welcome. Now put that into your bag of tricks. I'm sure you will find the technique comes in handy in many conditions.